# Magento Soap Api not working for Magento 2

Tags: api, magento, soap

In Magento 2, when i test its Soap API through Soap UI for any process , I get following error

> require() [<a
>   href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening
>   required 'Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api/v2.php'
>   (include_path='/home/template/public_html/Individual/***/newmagento/magento2master/app/code/local:/home/template/public_html/Individual/***/newmagento/magento2master/app/code/community:/home/template/public_html/Individual/***/newmagento/magento2master/app/code/core:/home/template/public_html/Individual/**/newmagento/magento2master/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')

As my understanding it is unable to find the v2.php file, but in magento structure the v2 file is named as V2.php, where V is in capital case but it is looking for lowercase v2.php file as a result it cannot find the file.

Once I change the case of v2.php in magento everything is working fine, But this is not the solution for the issue.

Can anybody help me about this issue?

Comment: It is a known issue. Please wait until next github update.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i track this issue?